# How to make a part of a shape to have a specific width, while preserving the overall ratio?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector, shapes, transform, scale

[image]

As shown in the image, I have a blue phone icon, and I wish to have the width of the handset (red line) to match the width of the white rectangle (yellow line). How can I do this, while preserving the radio of the blue phone icon?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Yes you use the scale tool, **S** (not scale handles of arrow tools). move the scaling bands on top of each other.(this works better if they are not vertical, or horizontal so skew a bit first). Enable the scale tool. click on one of the ends of your measuring stick. then move your cursor so it snaps on the smaller measuring sticks end (and make sure it says anchor with smart guides enabled), then drag till it matches other sticks anchor holding shift down to constraint scale (if you skewed it then it scales proportionally otherwise it scales on axis)

Answer (score 1):

The graphical version of the scaling:

[image]

In the left the green square is as wide as the handset. It can be drawn exactly at least if you drag at first a couple of brand new vertical guides from the ruler to the edges of the handset. The orange square presents the wanted width of the handset. The icon is a single object - group or compound path.

In the middle the extras are scaled proportionally (hold Shift when you drag) to wider than the icon.

In the right: The icon and the green square are selected and scaled proportionally to the same width as the orange square. Now the handset is exactly as wide as wanted.

This works only if you have snap to points and smart guides ON.

Answer (score 0):

Divide the width of the yellow line by the width of the red line, and multiply by 100. This will give you the percentage for the enlargement. Select the graphic, and do *Object > Transform > Scale*, and select the *Uniform* scale option, and type in the percentage you calculated. Hit OK.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! But that seems like a brute force solution, I thought AI would have a more elegant way to do this lol. I actually thought of something similar: calculate the current ratio of the yellow width and the red width, and then just multiply the overall width of the phone icon with the ratio.

Comment: @GlenXoseph - multiplying by a ratio is exactly what scaling by a percentage does.  The other way would be to scale manually and hold down shift as you click and drag to maintain the aspect ratio while scaling, but that's hardly accurate, and will take a bit of tweaking to get the size right.